# How to checddsa hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I need to detect every change of variable state BUT check code:

```
  useEffect(() => {  
    if (value) {
        setSelect(value); 
    }
  }, [value]);
```

code above checkin every second and i got error:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
> doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
> every render.

I need to check only when value is changed not every second!

**value** is props data from parent component.

```
const OrganisationUnitInput = ({ 
  input
}) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const value = input.value || [];

 

const value = input.value || [];

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      input.onChange(value);
      setShowModal(false);
    },
    [input]
  );
    }
```

Comment: What is the type  of value? And why does it changes often?

Comment: why are you not making `value` a state variable??

Comment: value is array with objects [{id: 1 , name : "test'}] ... I don't know why is changes ofter

Comment: check my update on question

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you are setting value state and passing same value as dependency array . which results in re rendering

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the **useEffect** hook, when you pass the second argument with some variable you are telling to react that the function of the effect must be executed if the variable change.

So in your code You are making an infinity loop.

To detect the change on the var only pass the var in the array and your function will be executed if any change occurred.

```
const Comp = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        // This code will be execute any time that the var value
        // change

        console.log("The value change, now is: ", value)

        // so if you change the var here your will cause another call
        // to this effect.
    }, [value])
    
    return <button onClick={() => { setValue(prev => prev + 1) }}>
        Change Value
    </button>
}
```